# What is the easiest way to pause Consumer in P-C pattern?

Tags: c#, multithreading, producer-consumer

I have typical producer-consumer application. I have BlockingCollection to provide producing-consuming mechanism. What I need is to add ability to pause consumer thread execution from another thread. I've read about different .net synchronization primitives but I can't decide how to implement it in the easiest way.

P.S.: I use .net 4.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an AutoResetEvent and wait on it in the Consumer until the other thread wakes it up again, by setting it to signaled.

Comment: Thank you. I used EventWaitHandle since I need ability to control reset manually, but in in general your answer was helpful.